# How do I make my if/else if statement more compact/readable?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I have made a simple Rock Paper Scissors game that can be played in the console. It uses a series of if/else if statements to compare the inputs by the user against the computers selections and outputs a winner based on this. My issue is that the code is a bit long and repetitive so I'm not sure if there is a way to possibly make it more compact.

This is my code at the moment:

```
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection){

  if (computerSelection === playerSelection){
    return "It's a tie!"
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "paper"){
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors"){
    computerScore += 1;
    return "Computer wins!"; 
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "rock"){
    computerScore += 1;
    return "Computer wins!"; 
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "scissors"){
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "paper"){
    computerScore += 1;
    return "Computer wins!"; 
  }
  else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "rock"){
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
    
  }
  else{
    return "Invalid entry!"
  }

}
```

This is not all the code for the game, just the section that I'm looking to shorten.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a data driven system:

```
const winner = { scissors: 'rock', rock: 'paper', paper: 'scissors' }
  
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection)
  {
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection)  return "It's a tie!";
  if (playerSelection === winner[computerSelection]) { playerScore++;   return "You win!"; }
  if (computerSelection === winner[playerSelection]) { computerScore++; return "Computer wins!"; }
  return "Invalid entry!";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Very quickly, without switch/case and without making too many changes to your original code:

```
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection){
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection){
    return "It's a tie!"
  }
  if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "paper") ||
     (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "scissors") ||
     (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "rock"){
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
  }
  if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors") ||
     (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "rock") || 
     (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "paper"){
    computerScore += 1;
    return "Computer wins!"; 
  }
  return "Invalid entry!"
}
```

In my opinion, you don't need any `else` statement here and you can summarize conditions with the same outcome.

Please note, that I am pretty sure that you can make the code even shorter, but there is always a trade-off between readability and shortness. In addition, I chose code that is "similar" to the original  on purpose.

Comment: Actually, you can lose around half this code. The first two condition test for a tie, or a player win. For all other results, the computer wins. There's no need to check for the conditions explicitly.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular: I like your thought a lot, but how do you check for `  return "Invalid entry!"` if you get rid of the computer wins cases? Since I am not 100% sure what was needed, I am not sure if invalid cases are possible, but in plain JavaScript you can certainly write calls with invalid results.

Answer (score 1):

you can make like this:

```js
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  const winConditions = {
    rock: "scissors",
    paper: "rock",
    scissors: "paper"
  };

  if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  } else if (winConditions[computerSelection] === playerSelection) {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
  } else if (winConditions[playerSelection] === computerSelection) {
    computerScore += 1;
    return "Computer wins!";
  } else {
    return "Invalid entry!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter

```js
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
const win = {"rock"    : "scissors", 
             "paper"   : "rock", 
             "scissors": "paper"};
const start = (computerSelection, playerSelection) => {
  if(computerSelection === playerSelection) return "It's a tie!";
  if(win[computerSelection] === playerSelection) return ++computerScore, "Computer wins!";
  if(win[playerSelection] === computerSelection) return ++playerScore, "You win!";
  return "Invalid entry!";
};

/// tests
console.log("rock","scissors",start("rock","scissors"))
console.log("paper","scissors",start("paper","scissors"))
console.log("rock","rock",start("rock","rock"))
console.log("scissors","paper",start("scissors","paper"))
console.log("paper","rock",start("paper","rock"))

console.log(computerScore,playerScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  // Possible outcomes
  const outcomes = {
    rock: { scissors: 'Computer wins!', paper: 'You win!', rock: "It's a tie!" },
    paper: { rock: 'Computer wins!', scissors: 'You win!', paper: "It's a tie!" },
    scissors: { paper: 'Computer wins!', rock: 'You win!', scissors: "It's a tie!" }
  };
  // Tie?
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  }

  // Who won?
  if (outcomes[computerSelection][playerSelection] === 'You win!') {
    playerScore += 1; // Increment the player's score
  } else {
    computerScore += 1; // Increment the computer's score
  }

  // Return the outcome of the round
  return outcomes[computerSelection][playerSelection];
}
```

You can also add this:

```
// Are the selections valid choices?
  if (!(computerSelection in outcomes) || !(playerSelection in outcomes)) {
    return 'Invalid entry!';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the above code.

```js
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  let playerScore, computerScore;
  const outcomes = {
    rock: { scissors: 'Computer wins!', paper: 'You win!' },
    paper: { rock: 'Computer wins!', scissors: 'You win!' },
    scissors: { paper: 'Computer wins!', rock: 'You win!' }
  };
  if (!(computerSelection in outcomes) || !(playerSelection in outcomes)) {
    return 'Invalid entry!';
  }
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  }
  const outcome = outcomes[computerSelection][playerSelection];
  if (outcome) {
    if (outcome === 'Computer wins!') {
      computerScore += 1;
    } else {
      playerScore += 1;
    }
    return outcome;
  }
}
console.log(start("scissors","rock"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need to determine who wins. Here is one idea to do that.

[See also ...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scissorspaperrock?file=PlayFactory.js)

```js
const wins = {rock: `paper`, paper: `scissors`, scissors: `rock`};
const choices = Object.keys(wins);

function play(youSelection, pcSelection) {
  return `(you) ${youSelection} > (computer) ${pcSelection} => ${
    youSelection === pcSelection 
    ? `TIE` : youSelection === wins[pcSelection]
    ? `You win` : `Computer wins`}`;
}

// demo
for (let i=0; i < 10; i+=1) {
  const me = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  const pc = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  console.log(play(me, pc));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: That is SO unreadable. Especially compared to mine which is doing similar lookup

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without if else. Using TypeScript template literal types for type safety

```js
type Hand = "rock" | "paper" | "scissors";

const draw = { player: 0, computer: 0 };
const playerWins = { player: 1, computer: 0 };
const computerWins = { player: 0, computer: 1 };

const points: Record<`${Hand}-${Hand}`, { player: number; computer: number }> =
  {
    "paper-paper": draw,
    "rock-rock": draw,
    "scissors-scissors": draw,
    "paper-rock": playerWins,
    "rock-scissors": playerWins,
    "scissors-paper": playerWins,
    "rock-paper": computerWins,
    "scissors-rock": computerWins,
    "paper-scissors": computerWins,
  };

function rps(player: Hand, computer: Hand) {
  return points[`${player}-${computer}`];
}

console.log(rps("paper", "rock")); // {player: 1, computer: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you don't need to do this kind of if/else logic when returning in each block:

```
if (x) {
  return 'foo';
} else if (y) {
  return 'bar';
else {
  return 'lorem ipsum';
}
```

That can be written as just

```
if (x) {
  return 'foo';
} 

if (y) {
  return 'bar';
}

return 'lorem ipsum';
```

Secondly, if you want to use a switch statement, as you're not just checking a single value, you could try:

```
switch (true) {
    case computerSelection === playerSelection:
        return "It's a tie!";
    case computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "paper":
        return "You win!";
    case computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors": 
        return "Computer wins!"; 
    ... etc
    
    default:
        return "Invalid entry!"
}
```

Thirdly, in your function you increment `playerScore` and `computerScore`, but they're not initialised anywhere, and you don't use them anywhere.  So I removed them from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with regards to the playerScore and computerScore - they're initialised at the beginning of the file and then called in a separate function further down, both of which I left out of my post as I was just looking to shorten the else if statement I had.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `switch case` to write those statments,it will look like this:

```
function start(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  let result = "";
  switch (true) {
    case computerSelection === playerSelection:
      result = "It's a tie!";
      break;
    case computerSelection === "rock":
      result = playerSelection === "paper" ? "You win!" : "Computer wins!";
      break;
    case computerSelection === "paper":
      result = playerSelection === "scissors" ? "You win!" : "Computer wins!";
      break;
    case computerSelection === "scissors":
      result = playerSelection === "rock" ? "You win!" : "Computer wins!";
      break;
    default:
      result = "Invalid entry!";
  }
  if (result === "You win!") {
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (result === "Computer wins!") {
    computerScore += 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```